# Why is ReferenceEquals still used with value types?

Tags: c#, referenceequals

There is a nice [explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2013) why `object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)` must not be used for value types:

> When comparing values using ReferenceEquals, if objA and objB are
> value types, they are boxed before they are passed to the
> ReferenceEquals method. This means that even if both objA and objB
> represent the same instance of a value type, the ReferenceEquals
> method nevertheless returns false

However, I found code similar to the following snippet:

```
internal readonly struct Foo
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj is Foo other)
        {
            return this.Equals(other);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        // ..
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is this just wrong or is there an edge case in which `ReferenceEquals` could be useful (i.e., evaluate to true) for value types, especially structs?

Comment: Yeah, it's just wrong. `Foo` is a value type, so passing `this` to `object.ReferenceEquals` will box the instance itself. The newly boxed instance can't be equal to anything because that reference never existed before `Equals(object)` was called.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.  The StackOverflowException it generates ensures it won't be used.

Comment: Assuming there's no `Equals(Foo)` that just isn't included here.

Comment: I guess it's possible it might not throw a `StackOverflowException` if there's an overload `bool Equals(Foo obj)`.  I guess.

Comment: Yes, the `Equals(Foo obj)` implementation is omitted here.

Comment: @momo Can you add it to the question?  It's relevant, considering the comments.

Comment: for reference `obj is Foo other` is the [`is` type pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern) [introduced in C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be. The code as-written is simply bad, in that it unnecessarily boxes something for a test that will *never* work. For completeness, a more useful and idiomatic pattern in this case would be:

```cs
// custom Foo equality implementation
public bool Equals(Foo other)
{
    // ...
}
// default object implemenentation
public override int GetHashCode() {...} // must match Equals(Foo) logic
public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Foo other && Equals(other);
```